# Best way to create associative array of unique objects in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, object, associative-array

I'm trying to create a list of unique objects in PHP.
I want to access each object by a unique name but I also need the object to know its name.

My idea was to create an associative array of objects like this:

```
class MyObject()
{
    public $name;
    public $property1;
    public $property2;

    function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    function doSomething()
    {
        echo $name.$property1;
    }

    function doSomethingElse()
    {
        echo $name.$property2;
    }
}

$array = array();

$name = 'example';
$array[$name] = new MyObject($name);
$array[$name]->property1 = 'xyz';
$array[$name]->property2 = 123;

$name = 'test';
$array[$name] = new MyObject($uniqueName);
$array[$name]->property1 = 'abc';
$array[$name]->property2 = 321;

$array['example']->doSomething();
$array['test']->doSomethingElse();
```

I'm pretty new to PHP and coding in general and I feel like this is a really stupid solution so I wanted to ask if you know any better ways of doing this.

Comment: I personally think there would be one flow with this approach: using this code as is, you don't guarantee the uniqueness of this name. I would try to use a "master" object that deals with adding new objects and associate them with a unique name (stored in a private property), and ensure each time you try to add new objects that the name is not already used. This also offers the advantage of having a nice looking method like "getObjectByName(string $name)" and "addObject($object, string $name)".

Comment: What's a unique object?  Are two objects with the same properties deemed the same?

Comment: `$name` is an undeclared variable in your `doSomething` and `doSomethingElse` declarations.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple use-case you've provided, perhaps implementing the predefined interface `ArrayAccess` may fit the bill. Something like:

```
class UniqueCollection implements ArrayAccess
{
    /**
     * @var  array<string, MyObject>
     */
    private $collection = [];

    /**
     * @param  mixed  $offset
     *
     * @return  bool
     */
    public function offsetExists($offset): bool
    {
        return isset($this->collection[$offset]);
    }

    /**
     * @param  mixed  $offset
     *
     * @return  MyObject|null
     */
    public function offsetGet($offset): mixed
    {
        return $this->collection[$offset] ?? null;
    }

    /**
     * @param  mixed                $offset
     * @param  array<mixed, mixed>  $values
     *
     * @return  void
     */
    public function offsetSet($offset, $values): void
    {
        if ($offset === null) {
            // Error
        }

        // Uncomment if we don't want to overwrite existing MyObject with the same name,
        // eg, throw exception
        // if (isset($this->collection[$offset]) {
        //     // Error
        // }

        $count($values);
        if ($count !== 0 || $count !== 2) {
            // Error
        }

        $myObj = new MyObject($offset);
        if ($count) {
            // Fetch the values only so we only have to deal with zero-based integer offsets
            $values = array_values($values);
            // Establish a convention on which index goes to what property
            $myObj->property1 = $values[0];
            $myObj->property2 = $values[1];
        }

        $this->collection[$offset] = $myObj;
    }

    /**
     * @param  mixed  $offset
     *
     * @return  void
     */
    public function offsetUnset($offset): void
    {
        return unset($this->collection[$offset]);
    }
}
```

Use:

```
$set = new UniqueCollection();

$set['example'] = ['xyz', 123];

$set['test'] = [];  // not exactly elegent, but hey ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
$set['test']->property1 = 'abc';  // should work fine, unless we clone the MyObject internally
$set['test']->property2 = 321;  // ditto

$set['example']->doSomething();
$set['test']->doSomethingElse();
```

I haven't tested this so let me know if there are any issues.